# Regex - matching an arbitrary number of values (ruby)

Tags: ruby, regex

Some samples inputs

```
winning numbers: 1
winning numbers: 1,2,3,4
winning numbers: 1,23, 28,   273, 191
```

Desired matches

```
[1]
[1,2,3,4]
[1,23,28,273,191]
```

It is a simple pattern, but I'm not really sure how to match all of the numbers. I was thinking something like "get the first number, then zero or more numbers preceded by a comma and possibly spaces"

`winning numbers:\s*(\d+)\s*(,\s*(\d+))*`

But it only matches the first one (as expected), and the last number.

I'm using ruby, so I want to be able to retrieve all of the matches in an array and pass it off. With my current regex, it matches the last number, but it also matches the comma as well cause it's inside the parentheses.

Is my logic flawed? Or am I not expressing it as a regex correctly?
I'm using [rubular](http://rubular.com/) to test my regex.

Comment: Why don't you just extract the numbers string and then split by regex?

Comment: Hmm maybe I was too focused on writing a regex to parse the whole thing lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`scan`](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/scan) method to match all numbers and then [`map`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/map) them into the array with converting each one to integer using [`to_i`](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/to_i)

```
numbers = "1,23, 28,   273, 191"

numbers.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
 => [1, 23, 28, 273, 191]
```

Answer (score 0):

The original answer works well, but I'm always concerned that someday, someone is going to change the message text to include a number.

Here's another way this could be done:

```
2.3.0 :013 > def get_numbers(s)
2.3.0 :014?>   s.split(':').last.split(',').map(&:to_i)
2.3.0 :015?>   end
 => :get_numbers
2.3.0 :016 > get_numbers 'winning numbers: 1,23, 28,   273, 191'
 => [1, 23, 28, 273, 191]
```

Of course, this also contains an assumption, that there will always be exactly 1 colon in the line, and it will end the description text.